# Does some macro exist for creating this text effect?

Tags: after-effects

I'm referring to this [video (top right)](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/). How can I create a similar video / text effect. Indeed I can give expressions of the damped oscillator and tweak it for a long time until I get a good effect, but what would be a way way to do this? I prefer to use Adobe After Effects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Kinetic Typography piece. Search for templates on VideoHive, there are also plugins for AE that allow for easier generation of KT setups.

It's timeconsuming, search vimeo for some great samples: Kinetic Typography.

One of my all time favorites still to this day - produced years ago:  https://vimeo.com/17419652    The guy who did this spent months on it. But he did it all himself, great work.